# Div only transitions the second time a key is clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, keycode

I have a yellow div that moves left/up when the corresponding key is clicked. I want it to transition each times. This happens, but starting from the second time it is clicked. On the first click, it moves but there is no transition... What's wrong with my code?

```
.counter {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  transition: top linear 1s, left linear 1s;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```
<div class="counter" id="yellow">P1</div>
```

```
document.onkeydown = detectKey;

function detectKey(e) {

  var posLeft = document.getElementById('yellow').offsetLeft
  var posTop = document.getElementById('yellow').offsetTop

  if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    document.getElementById('yellow').style.left = (posLeft + 80) + "px"
  }
  if (e.keyCode == '38') {
    document.getElementById('yellow').style.top = (posTop - 50) + "px"
  }
}
```

Comment: Transitions only fire when there is a change in a set CSS attribute, not on initial set. So the first click sets it, and on the second click it transitions to the new value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to specify an initial top and left value in your CSS.
See the attached snipet.

```js
document.onkeydown = detectKey;

function detectKey(e) {

  var posLeft = document.getElementById('yellow').offsetLeft
  var posTop = document.getElementById('yellow').offsetTop

  if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    document.getElementById('yellow').style.left = (posLeft + 80) + "px"
  }
  if (e.keyCode == '38') {
    document.getElementById('yellow').style.top = (posTop - 50) + "px"
  }
}
```

```css
.counter {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  /*margin-top:-100px;
   margin-left:60px;*/
  transition: top linear 1s, left linear 1s;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 0; /* <<< */
  left: 0; /* <<< */
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter" id="yellow">P1</div>
```